# Оповещения на Nodejs, FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed

Tags: node.js, socket.io

День добрый, есть небольшой сервер на socket.io для оповещений на сайте. Через сутки падает с ошибкой, подозреваю что есть утечка памяти, как бы найти её, если же ошибаюсь в чем может быть проблема:

<--- Last few GCs —->

- [25967:0x37186a0] 94414193 ms: Mark-sweep 1430.1 (1508.6) -> 1430.1 (1508.6) MB, 246.8 / 0.1 ms  allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
- [25967:0x37186a0] 94414444 ms: Mark-sweep 1430.1 (1508.6) -> 1430.1 (1492.6) MB, 250.1 / 0.1 ms  last resort GC in old space requested
- [25967:0x37186a0] 94414708 ms: Mark-sweep 1430.1 (1492.6) -> 1430.1 (1492.6) MB, 263.9 / 0.1 ms  last resort GC in old space requested

  1: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3

  3: encodeAsString [/usr/lib/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:173] [bytecode=0x2ae6b9a7301 offset=152](this=0x163674a8be31 ,obj=0x7eee16e5e01

==== JS stack trace =========================================

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memoFycurity context: 0x18848d725ec1

1: node::Abort() [node]e: stringify(this=0x18848d709021 ,0xcdcbe582311 ,0x7eee16e5dc1

4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]

5: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawOneByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]

6: v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]

7: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeString(v8::internal::Handle) [node]

8: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_, bool, v8::internal::Handl ) [node]

9: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::SerializeArrayLikeSlow(v8::internal::Handle, unsigned int, unsigned int) [node]

10: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Serialize_, bool, v8::internal::Handle) [node]

11: v8::internal::JsonStringifier::Stringify(v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle, v8::internal::Handle) [node]

12: v8::internal::Builtin_JsonStringify(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]

13: 0x33b63490441d

Comment: Очевидно утечки. Есть куча статей как их искать.

Comment: Может быть подскажете что то стоящее?

Comment: Когда-то давно я делал по этой статье https://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-heap-snapshots/. Всё просто, снимаем дампы памяти в разное время и сравниваем что там лишнее копится. Наверное с тех пор появились другие инструменты

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю в этом направлении.